# How to properly protect a laptop placed in a checked in luggage?

Tags: air-travel, usa, electronic-items

The US seems to make it increasingly difficult to have a laptop in carry-on luggage in airplane.

Examples:

- The Daily Beast  2017-05-10: [U.S. to Ban Laptops in All Cabins of Flights From Europe, Officials Say](https://redd.it/6af5g5)
   ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170511011217/https://www.reddit.com/r/news/comments/6af5g5/us_to_ban_laptops_in_all_cabins_of_flights_from/))).
- Reuters 2017-05-28: [U.S. might ban laptops on all flights into and out of the country](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-airlines-electronics-idUSKBN18O0KL) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170528205210/https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-airlines-electronics-idUSKBN18O0KL))

How to properly protect a laptop placed in a checked-in luggage?

Comment: NB: [*US and EU reject expanding laptop ban to flights from Europe*](http://www.bbc.co.uk/news/world-europe-39956968) (17 May).

Comment: @gerrit Reuters 2017-05-28:  [U.S. might ban laptops on all flights into and out of the country](https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-airlines-electronics-idUSKBN18O0KL) ([mirror](https://web.archive.org/web/20170528205210/https://www.reuters.com/article/us-usa-airlines-electronics-idUSKBN18O0KL))

Answer (score 6):

Considering these bags will be thrown, dropped, dropped on, exposed to unknown temperatures and possibly vulnerable to theft, there is no *proper* way to do it. Wrapping it with a significant amount of clothing will surely protect it from *some* shock damage. One of those big business laptop bags will help too if that fits in your suitcase or backpack. A hard-shell suitcase will be better than a soft-shell suitcase or even backpack, as long as the laptop cannot toss around inside. But ultimately, unless you can professionally package it for this kind of transport, it's no way to handle electronics.

Comment: I agree; it ought to be packaged in its original packaging or something close to it.

Answer (score 4):

The normal means of protecting stuff like this is a rigid case with foam inside with holes that match what you are trying to protect.

While I have never used their air travel versions I have used Pelican cases before for transport protection.  They're heavy and pricey but the stuff inside survived being dropped more than once.